# Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: запрос, база-данных, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
                pd.name AS name,
                p.image,
                m.name AS manufacturer,

  (SELECT price
   FROM oc_product_discount pd2
   WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id
     AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1'
     AND pd2.quantity = '1'
     AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00'
           OR pd2.date_start < '2014-08-23 10:21:00')
          AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00'
               OR pd2.date_end > '2014-08-23 10:21:00'))
   ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount,

  (SELECT price
   FROM oc_product_special ps
   WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id
     AND ps.customer_group_id = '1'
     AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00'
           OR ps.date_start < '2014-08-23 10:21:00')
          AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00'
               OR ps.date_end > '2014-08-23 10:21:00'))
   ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,

  (SELECT points
   FROM oc_product_reward pr
   WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id
     AND customer_group_id = '1') AS reward,

  (SELECT ss.name
   FROM oc_stock_status ss
   WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id
     AND ss.language_id = '1') AS stock_status,

  (SELECT wcd.unit
   FROM oc_weight_class_description wcd
   WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id
     AND wcd.language_id = '1') AS weight_class,

  (SELECT lcd.unit
   FROM oc_length_class_description lcd
   WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id
     AND lcd.language_id = '1') AS length_class,

  (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total
   FROM oc_review r1
   WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id
     AND r1.status = '1'
   GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
   FROM oc_review r2
   WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id
     AND r2.status = '1'
   GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews,
                p.sort_order
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id)
WHERE p.product_id = '28'
  AND pd.language_id = '1'
  AND p.status = '1'
  AND p.date_available <= '2014-08-23 10:21:00'
  AND p2s.store_id = '0'
```

Вот в этом запросе ошибка, как пофиксить?

Comment: Рекомендую специальные сервисы для форматирования кода:


 - [http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html](http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html)
 - [http://sqlformat.org/](http://sqlformat.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема описана в заголовке вопроса. Один из Ваших подзапросов

```
(SELECT points
   FROM oc_product_reward pr
   WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id
     AND customer_group_id = '1') AS reward,

  (SELECT ss.name
   FROM oc_stock_status ss
   WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id
     AND ss.language_id = '1') AS stock_status,

  (SELECT wcd.unit
   FROM oc_weight_class_description wcd
   WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id
     AND wcd.language_id = '1') AS weight_class,

  (SELECT lcd.unit
   FROM oc_length_class_description lcd
   WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id
     AND lcd.language_id = '1') AS length_class,
```

вернул более одного значения (что недопустимо). Какой из них, Вам никто не скажет, т.к., не видя самих данных этого, сделать невозможно. Самое простое решение - это добавить к ним `LIMIT 1`, но вот насколько это будет корректно, решать только Вам.